# How to display max value from the group of column. max value should be different from pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, max, netezza

I have table A like this:

```
ID | L1   |L2   | Date         
-- |----- |---- | ---------
1  |  A   | B   | 2003-01-01
---|------|-----|----------
2  |  A   | B   | 2004-05-01
---|------|-----|----------
3  |  B   | C   | 2003-01-01
---|------|-----|-----------
4  |  B   | C   | 9999-12-31
---|------|-----|-----------
5  |  C   | D   | 1998-02-03
---|------|-----|-----------
6  |  C   | D   | 2004-05-01
```

Normal situation is when for a pair of letters (AB, BC, CD) is one date = '9999-12-31'. So for two pairs of letters (AB, CD) I miss the date '9999-12-31'
and I need to write a query to see those letters and IDs.

I wrote a query like (to see the max date of pair of letters)

```
select distinct L1, L2, max(date) from A GROUP BY 
L1, L2
having max(date)<>'9999-12-31'
```

This query shows correct rows but I need to also see IDs and this is something I couldn't do. Does anyone knows how to write the query to see IDs also? ID is always unique

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not clear. So you eliminate B,C because at least one row has the date in 9999. That seems clear. But then, for A,B do you want both rows, or only the one with the highest date? Same for C,D.

Comment: I want to display in the query the highest date for this pair of letters that don't have date = '9999-12-31'. So in the result of the query I need to have A,B and C,D with the highest dates for both.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon offered a solution if you want all the rows for the pairs L1, L2 that don't have any date equal to 9999-12-31.

Here is a solution in case you were looking only for the pairs L1, L2 that don't have any date equal to 9999-12-31, and for those pair, you only wanted the row with the latest date.

```
with
     table_A ( id, l1, l2, dt ) as (
       select 1, 'A', 'B', date '2003-01-01' from dual union all
       select 2, 'A', 'B', date '2004-05-01' from dual union all
       select 3, 'B', 'C', date '2003-01-01' from dual union all
       select 4, 'B', 'C', date '9999-12-31' from dual union all
       select 5, 'C', 'D', date '1999-02-03' from dual union all
       select 6, 'C', 'D', date '2004-05-01' from dual
     )
select id, l1, l2, dt
from (
       select id, l1, l2, dt,
              row_number () over (partition by l1, l2 order by dt desc) rn
       from   table_A
     )
where rn = 1
and   dt != date '9999-12-31'
;

    ID L1 L2 DT                
------ -- -- -------------------
     2  A  B 2004-05-01 00:00:00
     6  C  D 2004-05-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. However I cannot apply your solution because values from table A are hardcoded (in CTE). The table I have provided is just a "sample" of my real table. My real table has over 5 milions rows and too many combinations of 4 columns. It's not possible to write a query like yours... Do you have any other idea? Some kind of dynamic (not hard coded) solution?

Comment: If you have your own table, you don't need `table_A` from my solution at all. The query begins at `select id, l1, l2, dt...` - just make sure your table is called `table_A`, or if it isn't then just change the name in the FROM condition. The CTE I created is a very common way to add some test data, but it is not part of the solution.

Comment: ok. Do you know then how the solution I need might look like?

Comment: I thought I already told you what it looks like. Delete everything from the word `with` to the closing parenthesis of the WITH clause. What is left, from the `select id, ...` to the closing semicolon `;` is your solution. Just make sure you use your actual table and column names (everywhere: in the `select` clauses, in the `partition by` and `order by` in the `row_number()` function, etc.) Also note that I changed your column name from "date" to `dt` - you shouldn't use reserved words for column names. Good luck!

Comment: I  reparaphrase your query so it could match my table, columns and it does not work... but in fact I run it on Netezza. Do you think that this is the reason why it does not work?

Comment: OK, first - this is bs, why do you tag Oracle if you don't use Oracle? I see you just edited your post to add `netezza`, why wasn't it there from the beginning? Second, I have no idea what Netezza is, but I just googled it and I see what it is. Then, I googled further and I see Netezza supports analytic functions, and in particular row_number. Perhaps the syntax is different; left to you, or to netezza experts, to help you if there are indeed syntax differences. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a a
where not exists (select 1
                  from a a2
                  where a2.l1 = a.l1 and a2.l2 = a.l2 and
                        a2.date = '9999-12-31'
                 );
```

This assumes that the "date" column is stored as a string, or that you have date format settings so `'9999-12-31'` is interpreted correctly (as is suggested by your sample query).  Otherwise, you can use:

```
a2.date = date '9999-12-31'
```

EDIT:

If you want the highest date for `l1`/l2` combos that don't have the maximum, that is easy:

```
select l1, l2, max(date)
from a
group by l1, l2
having max(date) < date '9999-12-31';
```

Comment: One question which is on my nerve.. Do you receive money of SO? What's your job? Answering in here? I'm saying that because you are here all the time .. So is being here your job?

Comment: @RGS You are a big follower of his answers? Heh .. When I ask a question about database, I wait **only** for his answer, and I rely on his answers as documentation .. So I guess I'm a bigger follower than you `:-)` .. But you know? That's Odd .. Why he spends lots of his time in here? What benefit he takes of being activate in here?

Comment: Hi Gordon! Thank you for your query but it does not meet the criteria of the task because it shows all the dates for these pair of L1, L2 that don't have date = 9999-12-31 but I need to see the highest date for these pairs that don't have date = 9999-12-31.... Do you know how to write someting like this?

Comment: Hey @stack - Why "on your nerve"? What has Gordon done to you? Why do you care what his job is, or if SO pays him? I don't recall Gordon ever being mean or disrespectful to anyone - that would perhaps justify "being on your nerves." Do you have a problem with his answer? Then point it out, but why the personal stuff?

Comment: Hi guys. please do not put a comment which is not relevant to the issue.... Thanks. Let's focus on the problem .... it seems not very easy to figure out...

Comment: hi Gordon again. Sorry but it's still not correct... I need to see all the columns from the table, not just 3 of them.